# Edit HTML5 presentation without coding

Tags: javascript, html, editor, wysiwyg, presentation

There are several libraries which allow you to create very sophisticated presentations in web browser:

- [impress.js](http://bartaz.github.com/impress.js/)
- [Google slides](http://code.google.com/p/html5slides/source/browse/trunk/template/index.html)
- [deck.js](http://imakewebthings.com/deck.js/#intro)
- [Reveal.js](http://lab.hakim.se/reveal-js/)

But the only way to edit these presentations is in code. Does anybody know one where the user can make edits on the fly in the browser?

And if so, if it is possible to get a representation of the presentation (i.e. in JSON) that could then be persisted?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Found Aloha Editor in Google, looks like it might do this (I've not tried it), allows you to edit impress.js presentations with WYSIWYG tools, no idea if you can save them but maybe you could save the raw HTML to persist them.

Blog about it: http://aloha-editor.org/blog/2012/04/impress-js-editable-with-wysiwyg-aloha-editor/

Demo: http://bit.ly/LZUaZP

Answer (score 2):

Checkout http://strut.io/

It is open source and supports Impress, Bespoke and Handout.

Once can easily import/export JSON data.

Answer (score 1):

An in-browser editor was recently released for reveal.js, you can try it here: http://www.rvl.io/

Comment: rvl.io now seems to be slid.es which turned into slides.com. As far as I can see only payed plans available.

Answer (score 0):

Old question, I know, but I was looking for the same today. Found this nice overview article covering tools, editors, libraries and overall technology around browser based presentations.

From the: Salisbury University Library
[Presenting Your Research: Browser-Based Presentations](https://libraryguides.salisbury.edu/c.php?g=200778&p=1320229)